# Extrema of Variable End Point problem

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

> Among all curves whose end points lie on two given vertical lines $x=a $ and $x=b $, find the curve for which the functional $$J [y] = \int_a^b F (x,y,y')dx $$ has an extremum

Similar to the case of fixed end points, we end up with the variation of $J $ equaling:
$$\delta J = \int_a^b (F_y-\frac {d}{dx} F_{y'})h (x)dx+F_{y'}h(x)|_a^b $$

Where $\delta J = 0$ implies it is at an extremum. This time, however, the boundary does not necessarily vanish.

If we consider the case that $h (a)=h (b)=0$, then $y(x) $ is a solution to Euler's equation, as the boundary terms vanish and:

**Theorem**

Let $f $ be a continuous function. If
$$\int_a^b f(x)h (x)dx=0$$
For all differentiable functions $h $ **satisfying h (a)=h (b)=0**, then $f (x) \equiv 0$.

This theorem is pivotal in deriving the Euler equation.

My book says that in order for the curve $y (x) $ to be a solution to the variable end point problem, it must be a solution to Euler's equation (i.e. an extremal).

Why must $y $ be extremal? It seems to me that by the theorem, $y $ is extremal when $h (a)=h (b)=0$, but I do not necessarily see why it needs to solve Euler's equation anywhere else (and thus force the boundary of $F_{y'} $ to vanish.

The way my book derived the Euler equation, it is *necessary* for the boundary of the perturbation to vanish:

If anyone wants a source/derivation on this material, click [here](http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc/node32.html)

Comment: It is said that it's because variations with zero variation at the boundary are still allowed and these imply the Euler-Lagrange quations. Nevertheless, I'm with you wondering why this excludes the possibility for extrema with both terms different of zero.

Comment: @RafaBudría: Yes, I agree in the case that the boundaries of the perturbation vanish. I just don't understand why it still must solve it when the boundaries are not $0$. It seems contradictory from the derivation for the Euler-Lagrange equation, in which we assume the perturbation vanishes at the boundary

Answer (score 1):

If you have an extremum, then $\delta J=0$ for all $h$. Now consider only all those $h$ such that $h(a)=h(b)=0$. Then you can apply your theorem to get that $F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y^\prime}=0$. 
Now go back to $\delta J=0$ but now with $h$ not vanishing at the endpoints. Since you  now know that $F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y^\prime}=0$ you now have $0=\delta J=F_{y^\prime}h(x)\vert^b_a$ and so if you take first $h$ with $h(a)=0$ and $h(b)=1$ you get $F_{y^\prime}=0$ at $b$. Then you take $h$ with $h(a)=0$ and you get $F_{y^\prime}=0$ at $a$. Was this your question?

Comment: Sort of, though I'm admittedly still a little wary. My confusion came from the fact that finding $F_y-\frac {d}{dx} F_{y'}=0$ depended on $h $ vanishing at the boundary. Is the idea that this quantity does not depend on $h $, so it remains true regardless of what $h $ is? If so, I don't see why the theorem I stated requires that $h $ vanish at the boundary. It seems we could just choose an $h $ that does, find that $f(x) \equiv 0$, and then say $h $ no longer vanishes at the boundary and the result would still hold, as $f$ was already found to be $0$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your theorem is also true if you do not require $h$ to vanish at the endpoints, since if the integral $\int fh=0$ for all $h$ in particular $\int fh=0$ for all $h$ vanishing at the endpoints. The point is that in the theorem it is enough to use functions which vanish at the endpoints. In a theorem it is better to assume as less as possible.

Comment: Well the theorem assumes that $h(a)=h (b)=0$, which is assuming more than a general $h $. I don't see how the prior necessary leads into the latter, though it may be semantics. The case that it does vanish at the boundaries already gave us the information we needed about $F $ and $y $ if I understand correctly.

Comment: you are assuming less, not more. The theorem would be true also if you only consider $h=\chi_{(c,d)}$ for all $a<c<d<b$. The smaller is the class of $h$ you consider, the better is the theorem. You are not assuming more hypotheses.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not seeing how that is assuming less. Imposing that $h $ be $0$ on the boundary is definitely more assumptions imposed on $h $. Do you mean that it's less assumptions in the sense that we are requiring a smaller class of functions to satisfy $\int fh =0$? Still, from what I understand now, it wouldn't matter if the theorem held for the case that $h $ does not disappear on the boundary, as the case where it does vanish encodes all the information we need about  $y $?

Comment: yes you are correct. Say that you have two sets $X_1\subset X_2$ and you have two theorems. The theorems have the same conclusion but in Theorem 1 you assume that a property if true for all $h\in X_1$ and in Theorem 2 you assume that a property if true for all $h\in X_2$. Now if you want to use the theorem you need to check the hypothesis. Which theorem is better (which theorem would be easier to use)?

Comment: Got it, thank you for your help. I was merely misunderstanding what you were putting conditions on when you were saying "less assumptions". The main takeaway I got from this is that since the information we got about yy (that it solves the Euler equation) is independent of hh, it it will hold true for all hh regardless of the fact that we used a particular class of hh to get the information. Is this correct?

Comment: @Gio67, sincerely, I don't consider satisfactory the explanation. It seems we are searching the extrema for a special class of functions: those satisfying the E-L equations, but this is **not** the problem posed.